# C# Overload IEnumerable Key/Value Type and non Key/Value

Tags: c#

I hope Key/Value Type call `Execute<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> enums)`,non Key/Value Type call `Execute<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enums)`

But Dictionary object will call `Execute<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enums)` instead of  `Execute<TKey, TValue>(this ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> enums)`

Ex:

```
void Main(){
    var keyValueTypeData = new[] {
        new Dictionary<string, string> (){{"Name" , "ITWeiHan" }}
    }.AsEnumerable();
    keyValueTypeData.Execute(); //call Execute<T>

    var nonKeyValueTypeData = new[] {new {Name ="ITWeiHan" }};
    nonKeyValueTypeData.Execute(); //call Execute<T>
}

public static class Test
{
    public static void Execute<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>> enums){}

    public static void Execute<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enums){}
}
```

Comment: An array of dictionary is not an ienumerable of KVPs. What makes you think it is?

Comment: i use ToList() or .AsEnumerable() , it also call Execute<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enums){}

Comment: It doesn't matter what you do to it - it just **isn't** that. A bag of egg cartons is not a collection of eggs. It is a collection of collection of eggs.

Comment: @mjwills yes, you're right. i fix my question.`IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>> enums`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array of `Dictionary` is **not** an `IEnumerable` of `KeyValuePair` (a single `Dictionary` is - but that isn't what you have).

I suspect what you meant to do is:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    public static class Test
    {
        public static void Execute<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>> enums)
        {

        }

        public static void Execute<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enums)
        {
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> data = new[] {
                new Dictionary<string, string> (){
                    {"Name" , "ITWeiHan" }
                }
            };
            data.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that part of the solution is to be explicit about the type - to ensure that the compiler is 'encouraged' to choose the method I want it to select.

i.e. I use `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>` rather than `var`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
static void Main()
{
    var keyValueTypeData = new[] {
        new Dictionary<string, string> (){{"Name" , "ITWeiHan" }}
    };
    keyValueTypeData.SelectMany(x => x.AsEnumerable()).Execute(); //call Execute<TKey, TValue>

    var nonKeyValueTypeData = new[] { new { Name = "ITWeiHan" } };
    nonKeyValueTypeData.Execute(); //call Execute<T>
}
```

Note the use of `SelectMany()` and `AsEnumerable()`.